# ERROR 9004 --- [ restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool : Unable to create initial connections of pool

Tags: spring-boot

I can not connect MySQL by Spring Boot. I code with IntelliJ and it's still not working. Someone help me do this!!! Thank you!!
[This is application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdIZL.png)

[And this is library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEGY2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes:
1. User name and password is incorrect.
2. Mysql service is not ready.

Have you tried accessing mysql with your username and password in the terminal to see if it's accessible?

Comment: Thank you!
I tried accessing mysql with your username and password and it's still working.
But in IntelliJ still show that error.

Comment: The host you are working within the MySQL picture is 'ADMIN' while in the JDBC configuration you try to access 'localhost'. Is your hostname different than localhost?